# How do I get id of a widget that invoke an event (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have these set of rectangles drawn on a canvas. They are all bind to Button-1 event. What I like to do is set a variable with an id of a widget that invoke the event. Here's a pseudo code of what I like to do

```
def clicked(e): #event handler. Binds to rectangle objects
    selected_button = e.widgets.get_id()
```

P.S : Although I bind the event handler to those rectangles objects only, when I place code e.widget.destroy() inside that handler, the canvas is destroyed as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Executive summary

Since canvas method accept indifferently tags or items id, you can use the compact callback

```
def autodestroy(event):
    event.widget.delete("current")
```

#### Details

Your callback receive a Tkinter *event* as unique parameter. This parameter is an object from whom you can retrieve stimulated *widget*, as well as other informations (mouse coordinate or buttons in the case of a mouse event).

```
def clicked(event):
    canvas = event.widget
```

To get the clicked canvas *item*, you can either use the `CURRENT`<sup>1</sup> tag

```
    rect = canvas.find_withtag("current")[0]
```

or reproduce picking with `find_closest`, `find_overlapping`, `find_enclosed` ...(copied from [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#coordinate-systems))

```
    canvas = event.widget
    x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    rect = canvas.find_closest(x, y)[0]
```

Note that `find_` family return tuples, that might be empty under some circumstance and you might test emptyness or catch exception.

Then to delete an *item* of a canvas, you can use `canvas.delete` method.

```
    canvas.delete(rect)
```

Since canvas method accept indifferently tags or items id, you can use a more compact writing:

```
def autodestroy(event):
    event.widget.delete("current")
```

<sup>1</sup> `Tkinter.CURRENT` and `"current"`are equivalent

Comment: Sorry for my late reply but thank you for your through explanation.It clears up!